# Passar dados de uma tabela para um input para fazer update

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

Boa noite, eu to aprendendo php e fazendo um CRUD pra treinar, consegui fazer o select na tabela e o insert para adicionar novos dados, mas queria que ao clicar no botão editar, abrisse um modal bootstrap (ja adicionei) com os dados selecionados dentro dos inputs pra atualização (essa parte não estou sabendo fazer). Será que alguém pode me ajudar nisso? Me desculpem caso já tenha algum post falando sobre isso.

conexao.php

```
<?php
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $dbname = "locadora";    

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

    if(!$conn){
        die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    function conectaBanco(){
        $bd = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "locadora");
        return $bd;
    }
?>
```

Tabela com botão editar para modal em funcionarios.php

```
<table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Código</th>
                  <th scope="col">CPF</th>
                  <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                  <th scope="col">Salário</th>
                  <th scope="col">Ação</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

            <tbody>
            <?php 
                foreach ($grupo as $row) { 
            ?>            
                <tr>
                  <th><?=$row["codigo"]?></th>
                  <td><?=$row["cpf"]?></td>
                  <td><?=$row["nome"]?></td>
                  <td><?=$row["salario"]?></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <form name="editar" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="idEditar" value="" />
                            <input class="btn btn-success" name="editar" type="button" value="Editar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Atualizar Funcionário">
                        </form>

                        <form name="deletar" action="../acao/excluir.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="idExcluir" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="excluir" />
                            <input class="btn btn-danger" name="deletar" type="submit" value="Deletar">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>           

                    <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">

                              <!-- Modal Cabeçalho -->
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Atualizar Funcionário</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                              </div>

                              <!-- Modal Corpo -->
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                <form method="POST" action="acao/atualizar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoFuncionario" placeholder="Código..." value="">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cpfFuncionario" placeholder="CPF..." value="">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomeFuncionario" placeholder="Nome..." value="" >
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="salarioFuncionario" placeholder="Salário" value="" >
                                  </div>                                  
                                </form>
                              </div>

                              <!-- Modal Footer -->
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Atualizar</button>
                              </div>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

            <?php 
             }
            ?>

              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Fica faltando só a função na tabela atualizar.php pra fazer SELECT nos dados e mostrar dentro dos inputs do modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você possui alguns erros na lógica vamos a eles:

1. O botão `editar` da tabela não precisa estar dentro de um `form` pois ele apenas disparará a ação de abrir a modal.
2. Não é necessário ter uma modal para cada linha da tabela. Apenas uma modal é necessário para isso, logo, o código da modal precisa estar fora do loop.

Uma vez que você já possui os dados de um funcionário em um array, basta serializá-lo com `json_encode` e adicioná-lo ao botão que vai disparar a modal. (no exemplo eu escolhi o nome do atributo como `data-funcionario` mas poderia ser `data-qualquer-coisa`)

Como a api do jQuery.data já faz o parse do `json` para nós, não precisaremos nos preocupar com isso, bastando acessar `$('button').data('funcionario')` que já virá um objeto `json` para manipularmos.

Mas para isso funcionar é muito importante que o valor atributo `data-funcionario` do botão seja criado com aspas simples `'` para não dar conflito com as aspas duplas `"` do json serializado pelo php.

Seguindo a [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) da modal do bootstrap para este caso temos:

```php
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Código</th>
            <th scope="col">CPF</th>
            <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            <th scope="col">Salário</th>
            <th scope="col">Ação</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($grupo as $row): ?>            
    <tr>
      <th><?php print $row["codigo"];?></th>
      <td><?php print $row["cpf"];?></td>
      <td><?php print $row["nome"];?></td>
      <td><?php print $row["salario"];?></td>
      <td>
        
        <button 
            type="button" 
            class="btn btn-success" 
            data-toggle="modal" 
            data-target="#exampleModal" 
            data-funcionario='<?php print json_encode($row)?>'>Editar</button>
        
        <form name="deletar" action="../acao/excluir.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="idExcluir" value="<?php print $row['codigo']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="excluir" />
            <input class="btn btn-danger" name="deletar" type="submit" value="Deletar">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>                   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Cabeçalho -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Atualizar Funcionário</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <form method="POST" action="acao/atualizar.php">
      <!-- Modal Corpo -->
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoFuncionario" placeholder="Código...">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cpfFuncionario" placeholder="CPF...">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomeFuncionario" placeholder="Nome...">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="salarioFuncionario" placeholder="Salário...">
          </div>                                  
      </div>

      <!-- Modal Footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Atualizar</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

E para finalizar o processo de jogar os dados do funcionário desejado para a modal precisaremos do seguinte `js`:

```js
<script>
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  var funcionario = button.data('funcionario'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
  console.log(funcionario);

  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('[name="codigoFuncionario"]').val(funcionario.codigo);
  modal.find('[name="cpfFuncionario"]').val(funcionario.cpf);
  modal.find('[name="nomeFuncionario"]').val(funcionario.nome);
  modal.find('[name="salarioFuncionario"]').val(funcionario.salario);
});
</script>
```

#### Referências:

- PHP [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php)
- jQuery [data api](https://api.jquery.com/data/)
- Bootstrap [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

Comment: Obrigado. Ótima explicação e a script funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: ele só atualiza uma linha da tabela. Digamos que tem 5 funcionarios na tabela, ele só atualiza 1, se eu clicar nos outros, vai aparecer os dados tudo certinho no modal, mas não realiza o update dos outros, apenas de 1

Comment: Sim, você não tem como atualizar dados do usuário com id 2 preenchendo dados do id 1